Is SimpleCredentialProvider Class obsolete for security vulnerabilities, or just dropped support?
My team is implementing a microsoft teams messaging bot. Our backend is a .net MVC app that targets .net framework 4.8 and we cannot update to .net core.
We tried bringing in the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.WebApi package, which says it supports our tech stack, but when we try to create a SimpleCredentialProvider, it says it is obsolete.
Microsoft Bot Connector Simple Credential Provider
Does anyone know why it is marked as obsolete?
If it is a security vulnerability, we will have to figure out something else.
If it is not a security issue, we may continue forward.
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            var credentialsProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(AppSettings.MicrosoftTeamsAppId, AppSettings.MicrosoftTeamsAppPassword);
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

